# hd-p2 with 32gb compact flash

Tags: tascam

would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. http://tascam.com/content/downloads/products/83/e_hd-p2_readme_vd.pdf, page 7.

Comment: also I sent an email to them and they told me that it needs the last firmware upgrade. 

Comment: Yes, that PDF is describing the version history of the firmware.